# Selecting a matrix row by name Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix in Mathematica defined as `A = {{"a", 1, 2}, {"b", 3, 4}}`.

How do I select row `"a"` **by name**??

Everything I try just returns `{}`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Untested, no Mathematica installation on this computer

```
Cases[A, {"a",_,_}]
```

As usual with Mathematica, there are likely to be other ways too.  Probably best not to think of `A` as a matrix either, but as a list of lists.  And for future reference: you should really report everything you have tried.

Comment: Thanks! That is so strange... It works with the minimal example I posted but not with the more complicated version that I actually want to use! I have imported a cvs file using 

data = Take[Import["filepath/file.csv", "CSV"]] 

and the first item in every row is a string (I checked using Head[data[[1,1]] but if I try Cases[data, {"cec_DCs", _, _}] i get {}. cec_DCs is the string at data[[1,1]]

Comment: *It works with the minimal example I posted but not with the more complicated version that I actually want to use*  Ask the questions you want answered, not simplified versions of them.  Don't ask, or extend, questions in comments, be serious, can you figure out source code written in a comment ?

Comment: @Steph D I just tried his code, both with "a" and with "cec_DCs" and each works. Look at the row in the matrix using FullForm and see if there is anything hidden in the string that might be making this fail. If that doesn't work then restart Mathematica, don't do anything prior to the Import and Cases and see if that fixes it. If that doesn't work then host your csv file somewhere that people can grab it without registering, logging in, etc. and let someone else see why the string is not matching. AND you can edit into your original post above all the needed information.

Comment: note this answer assumes you have *exactly* two additional columns.  You might try `Cases[ A  , {"a", __}]` (thats two underscores) which will match any number of columns

Comment: The double underscore worked! Thank you all so much for your help! Steph